# Doctrine: Filter entities by related values

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

So, I have this (seemingly very simple) problem: I have a Doctrine entity, a `Plan`. `Plan`s have associated `Feature`s (with a `value` property), these have associated `FeatureTypes`.

Now, given a list of `FeatureType` IDs and the possible values for each of these, I want to filter through all `Plan` entities.

My entities are pretty much like this:

```
Plan
- id
- features (One-to-Many)

Feature
- id
- plan (Many-to-One; column would be plan_id)
- featureType (Many-to-One; column would be featureType_id)
- value

FeatureType
- id
```

What I mean is this: There is an array like this one:

```
[
    1 => [
        '1 month',
        '3 months',
        '6 months',
    ],
    2 => [
        'Prepaid',
        'On Demand',
    ]
]
```

The keys are `FeatureType` IDs, the nested arrays are the `value`s I'm searching for. I want all `Plan`s that have a `Feature` associated for every `FeatureType` in the above array, where this `Feature`'s `value` also is in the array from above.

From all I can tell, the only solution is to simply get all Plans, and then filter through them in PHP after the fact. I don't really like that approach though. Is it possible to do this directly in Doctrine somehow?

Comment: Please show your entities.

Comment: @StephanVierkant Updated my question accordingly – is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it appears that I have found an answer (even though this is still not as clean as I had hoped).

I'm now looping through the array (`$features`), adding a conditional INNER JOIN for every parameter:

```
$i = 0;

foreach ($features as $feature => $values) {
    $qb->innerJoin('plan.features', "feature_{$i}", 'WITH', "feature_{$i}.featureType = :featureType_{$i} AND feature_{$i}.value IN (:values_{$i})")
        ->setParameter("featureType_{$i}", $feature)
        ->setParameter("values_{$i}", $values);

    $i++;
}
```